# Magicsuggest - CSS is weird when using with Bootstrap 3 and Jquery 2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magicsuggest

Been struggling with this for some time now. Funny how it's so easy to configure Magicsuggest but it's so difficult to make it look good in bootstrap.

I'm trying to put magicsuggest in my bootstrap page. But no matter what I do, it ends up looking like the images below:
[image]
[image]

I want it to look like a normal input box like this one:
[image]

I tried adding in the `cls` config option as `form-control` and also added in `form-control` to the magicsuggest `div` tag but neither of them worked.

Here's the HTML code I'm using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="magicsuggest"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="content">
      ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And the magicsuggest jquery code:

```
var ms = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
    valueField: 'id',
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    maxSelection: 1,
    resultAsString: true,
    method: 'get',
    data: result,
    renderer: function(data) {
      return data.name + " (" + data.year +")";
    }
  });
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.2, Jquery 2.1.3 and MagicSuggest 2.1.4

EDIT: So, I got it to sort of work with a strange hack. It looks like the elements aren't getting the `form-control` class applied correctly. It gets applied to the outer `div` and completely skips the `input` button. So I added the following lines after instantiating magicsuggest and it *looks* okay. It still has issues when you enter a value and select the suggestion:

```
  var ms = $('#magicsuggest').magicSuggest({
    valueField: 'id',
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    maxSelection: 1,
    resultAsString: true,
    method: 'get',
    data: result,
    renderer: function(data) {
      return data.name + " (" + data.year +")";
    }
  });
  // Hack for Magicsuggest
  $('#magicsuggest').removeClass("form-control");
  $("#magicsuggest div input").addClass("form-control")
  // End hack
```

Answer (score 0):

My apologies - the problem was I forgot to configure the routes to pick the CSS file correctly. That's what was messing up the whole appearance. The problem wasn't with the plugin, it was me :'(